# Triggering an animation when in view

Tags: jquery, triggers, scroll

I'm building a webpage where you can scroll-sideways or use buttons for "new pages" (note; when you use buttons, you slide through the previous pages with speed, it doesn't load a new page).

When a designated page comes into view, it should trigger an animation I made with flash.
I converted it via swiffy, and it works. Triggering the animation works just fine but the problem is: when for example you press the button wich would lead you to the page AFTER the page with the animation, the "page" still triggers because its been in view one time.

Now I'm trying to use a timeOut to delay the animation so that when you scroll by it, it shouldn't trigger except for when you linger on the page for more than X seconds.

Here's my current script:

```
    var $AnimatieAan = false;
    var $Zichtbaar = false;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $e = $('#searchEngine');

        var visible = $(window).scrollLeft()+window.innerWidth>$e.offset().left&&$(window).scrollLeft()<$e.offset().left+$e.width();

            if(visible)
            {
                $Zichtbaar = true;
                var Timer = setTimeout(function()
                {
                    console.log('timerstart');

                    if($Zichtbaar)
                    {
                        //$Zichtbaar = true;
                        console.log($Zichtbaar)
                        $AnimatieAan = true;
                        $Zichtbaar = false;
                        if($AnimatieAan)
                        {
                            var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('searchEngine'), mexaleSearch);
                            stage.start();
                            console.log(visible);
                            $AnimatieAan = false;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            clearTimeout(Timer);

                            console.log('clearTimeout');
                            $Zichtbaar = false;
                            $AnimatieAan = false;
                            stage.stop();
                        }
                    }                       
                } , 2000 );
            }
```

Clarification on how the scrolling works, a working version is on www.mexale.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What **exactly** is your question?

Comment: The animation does trigger, but it triggers ALL the time, so instead of only triggering when you linger on the page for X (in this case 2) seconds, it triggers anyway. Am I doing something wrong with the timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

1. Because `Timer` is a local variable inside the `scroll` handler, you’ll get a fresh, totally unrelated variable every time a scroll event happens. That means that the value of `Timer` is not remembered from one event to the next. To fix this, make a single `var Timer` outside the scope of the `scroll` handler function.
2. The `scroll` handler doesn't do anything if `visible` turns out to be false. When the user scrolls so that the animation isn’t visible, you want two things to happen: (a) the timeout should be cancelled; (b) the swiffy animation should be stopped. Instead, nothing happens, because the `if (visible)` block doesn't have an `else` block.
3. At the point where the code says `if($AnimatieAan)`, the variable `$AnimatieAan` is always true. (We just set it to true two lines before.) So the `else` block there can’t run; it’s impossible.

The code you have in that `else` block looks about right, but it is definitely attached to the wrong `if`.

Comment: Thanks alot!
I put the variables outside the scroll event, and gave the (visible) an else block and now it seems to work as I wanted. Some kinks here and there, but I will try to figure that out ;)